# do-release-upgrade command took up all my 1TB disk space

Tags: command-line, partitioning, gnome, upgrade, kubuntu

I am new to Linux. I have installed kubuntu using a USB boot on my new PC yesterday, and today I installed gnome as well. I was trying to set up my system and did some research. For some reason, I ran the command `sudo do-release-upgrade` and the command line started printing commands. I waited and got a notification saying that I do not have enough disk space. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gbsE.png) is what I see on my disk usage analyser.

Also, after the `Low Disk Space on "Filesystem root"` notification popped up, my PC freezes and both my mouse and keyboard cannot move. I tried to power off and power on again and nothing is showing after the Kubuntu logo.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

## **Update 1**

I went to recovery mode and used that terminal there.

### Output for `systemctl -p 0..3`:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twNbX.jpg)

### Output for `systemctl --list-boots`:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6Km6.jpg)

## Update 2

[More details from the Disk Usager Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5t2t.png)

Also, how do I clean up my disk space, will I need to give up my files? and clear my hard disk?

Comment: Please show `journalctl -p 0..3` Maybe something is filling your system logs or logrotate is not working. Also `journalctl --list-boots ` please edit your question for output.

Comment: @nobody I powered off my PC and tried to power on again but nothing is showing up anymore after the Kubuntu logo.

Comment: I’d be inclined to start again with the version of Ubuntu you want to run. The do-release-upgrade will upgrade you from one version to another, like 20.04 to 20.10. It can go wrong, perhaps if you didn’t fully update the starting version before doing the upgrade. So if you want Kubuntu 20.10 download the installation media for that version and update your usb. If you have any data on your broken installation that you want to keep just boot the installation usb, choose Try Ubuntu and copy the data to a external device.

Comment: @PonJar Thanks, what should I do now with my full disk? It is full now.

Comment: Your system seems to be filling /var/log, but you likely won't be able to open a multi-GB logfile to read what the problems are. Advice: Wipe-and-reinstall. Promptly begin monitoring your /var/log/syslog; if the problem re-occurs, catch it early so you have time to fix it.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks, do you mean that I can just delete my entire var/ file?

Comment: If you reinstall the system it should wipe the disk so you will start with plenty of space. I echo the advice of others to keep an eye on the logs. Use the systemctl -p 0..3 command  to see if anything bad is being generated.

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new to this. Can you please tell me how to reinstall the system? Do you mean to start with a fresh USB boot or do you mean any commands I have to enter in the terminal? Thanks.

Comment: Use the LiveUSB installer you already created. Boot from it. Select "Install Kubuntu". Then select "Erase Disk and Install Kubuntu".

Answer (score 0):

you have some kind of problem with a network device. (there I cannot help)

and persistentes journaling.

In recovery mode.

change in /etc/systemd/journald.conf

```
Storage=persistent
```

to

```
Storage=auto
```

rotate journal

```
journalctl --rotate
```

and

```
journalctl --vacuum-time=1s
```

Make a reboot in recovery mode an remove

```
rm -rf /var/log/journal
```

Identify oldest /var/log/syslog and kernlog

```
ls  /var/log/ | egrep 'syslog.*'
```

and for kern.log

```
ls  /var/log/ | egrep 'kern.log.*'
```

Example from me

```
kern.log
kern.log.1
kern.log.2.gz
kern.log.3.gz
kern.log.4.gz
```

remove all files with suffix .gz in both cases.

then try to reboot normal.

before you make your release upgrade, try to solve your problem with your network device.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I checked my `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` and `Storage` is already `auto`, and I checked my `/var/log/` and only found 4 files with `.gz`, which are `dmesg.[1-4].gz`, and the output for those two commands are `syslog` and `kern.log` respectively, should I remove these two files?